# Trouble with the method: setOnMyLocationChangeListener

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've been trying some tutorials and basic exercises with Google Maps V2 and I'm stuck with something happening to my "setOnMyLocationChangeListener" method.

I'm running the following code:

```
this.mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lon = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);

        Toast.makeText(
                GoogleMapsV2_Interact.this,
                "Coordss\n" + "Lat: " + lat + "\n" + "Lon: " + lon + "\n" , 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Event OnMyLocationChangeListener.");
    }
});
```

If I understand correct this whole event is supposed to trigger only when the Location of the "My Location blue dot shown on the map" changes... but everytime I run the code on my devide I keep getting spamed with the toast of my code like the event is being triggered nonstop.

Is there something I'm missing , or something I'm not understanding ? I thought I was supposed to see my toasts only and only after a location change for the blue dot.

Comment: I experienced this too and switched back to a plain old LocationListener with better results.

Comment: I worked on you suggestion and indeed the results are much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that

`Called when the Location of the My Location dot has changed (be it latitude/longitude, bearing or accuracy).`

Maybe your bearing or accuracy is changing all the time - print them with the coordinates into the LogCat and see what's different from the previous log statements.

Comment: You were right ! Thank you for the idea. The changes are very minimal but they are still there.

Comment: @Eversor I'm facing similar issue and wondering, how did you manage to prevent these small changes form happening?

Comment: You could register a minimum distance change by using `android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)` and filling in the `minDistance` parameter